# Storing binary data buffer in protocol buffer message

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a binary data buffer which i want to store in a protocol buffer.

In the documentation (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#scalar) it says that the `bytes` type is equivalent to `string` in C++. I could not believe this so i had to try it and yes, this seems to be the case..

This proto:

```
message BufferMsg {
  required bytes buffer = 1;
}
```

gives a message definition containing this:

```
private:
  ::std::string* buffer_;
```

The public setter/getter API looks like this:

```
  // required bytes buffer = 1;
  inline bool has_buffer() const;
  inline void clear_buffer();
  static const int kBufferFieldNumber = 1;
  inline const ::std::string& buffer() const;
  inline void set_buffer(const ::std::string& value);
  inline void set_buffer(const char* value);
  inline void set_buffer(const void* value, size_t size);
  inline ::std::string* mutable_buffer();
  inline ::std::string* release_buffer();
  inline void set_allocated_buffer(::std::string* buffer);
```

Surely, this cannot be the way to store binary data in a message. How should it be done? In C++ i would typically use an `unsigned char` array or something like that to store the data.

Comment: _"Surely, this cannot be the way to store binary data in a message. How should it be done?"_ What's your concern? I used that and it just works fine.

Comment: Is there no issue storing zeroes in a `std::string`?

Comment: No there never was an issue with storing `'\0'` in `std::string`. Length is tracked independently of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string`, although meant to be used for text data, isn't exactly bound to it. It does no validation, and has in general no restrictions on the contents of its buffer. So you can use it as a `std::vector<char>` if you have to.

Embedded zeros are only an issue if you use `c_str()` and C-style string functions to work on the result.

The main problem is that `char` may be signed on your platform, which makes it less convenient to work with as a byte type than `unsigned char`. I'm afraid that's just something you have to live with.

Comment: Should I copy the bytes to the string or just use set_mybuffer()?